# When do you create a custom function in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL. I have a database that is accessed by many servers. I need to create a custom MySQL function like this for example:

```
DELIMITER $$

create function calcDistance(lat float, lng float, pnt_lat float, pnt_lng float)

Returns float
BEGIN

Declare dist float;
SET dist =
  3959 * acos (
  cos ( radians(pnt_lat) )
  * cos( radians( lat ) )
  * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(pnt_lng) )
  + sin ( radians(pnt_lat) )
  * sin( radians( lat ) )
);

RETURN dist;

END
```

Since i want this function to be used by many servers, im wondering HOW and WHEN do i send this function to the database?

Since i have many servers that can crash and rebooted at anytime, do i resend this same function to MySQL everytime a server boots up, but before i start making queries? What happens if i send the same function more than once, since the servers wont know if the function was already sent to the database by another server.

I dont really know how it works...Does anybody know the answers to this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "send". We don't send anything to databases. Once you create the function in the database (by running the script in your question), it stays there and no need to do anything else.

Comment: @RacilHilan He didn't understand that this is saved on the database server, he thought it was something that happens on the client machine.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I know and that's why I explained almost the same as you did in your answer. But I've never seen the word "send" used even for queries or scripts that we run on the client side. Although it is technically right, but we just don't use it like that. We *send* commands or keystrokes, but we *run* scripts or queries. That's so funny, why do we use it like that? It's the same action for commands and scripts, but we use different words.

Comment: @RacilHilan He's apparently using PhpMyAdmin, so he types in a query and then sends it.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but we still call that "run", not "send". Is the execution button in PhpMyAdmin called "Send"? If so, then that explains. I never pay attention to the buttons whether they say "Send" or "Save" or "Submit" or whatever, so I don't remember what the button in PhpMyAdmin is called. But when we describe it, the action is always "run" for queries and scripts. Funny!

Comment: Such a big deal over one word. He's probably not a professional, he doesn't know the lingo.

Comment: No, no, not a big deal at all. Nothing wrong with his question, I was just making fun of how we say things. It has nothing to do with him.

Comment: when i said "send" i meant when you want the database to do something, you have to "send" the commands over the TCP/IP connection to the database where ever it is, then it does the command, and "sends"  back the result over the same TCP/IP socket connection, this is what i meant by "send". Thanks for answering the questions, i know im novice at MYSQL!

Comment: Yes Paul, you're absolutely right. I was making fun of us (professionals) how we use the term run (or execute) although it's technically wrong and the real action is actually send like you said, because you cannot run anything on the client, you'll have to send it to the database which will then run it. So from technical point of view, you are the correct one and we are the ones using the wrong terms. No worries, we all started as beginners. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to resend it. This is a *stored function*, it's saved on the database server just like tables are. Once it's created, any client can use it until you explicitly drop it.

Comment: What if the same function is sent to the database twice?

Comment: can the function be created using phpMyAdmin??

Comment: Yes it can. You can either enter the code into the SQL screen, or use the procedure builder.

Comment: It will be the same as if you "sent" the table twice: an error saying that a function already exists.

Comment: one last question, can the function once entered be used on all tables, or is it tied to a particular table or database?

Comment: Functions aren't used on tables, they're just called with values that can come from anywhere.

Comment: awesome!! Thanks all!

Comment: The function is stored in a database, but it can be called from any database. If your default db is the one containing the function, you can use `calcDistance()`, otherwise you need to use `dbname.calcDistance()`. Just like accessing a table or view.

Comment: i dont see anywhere in myphpAdmin to create a custom function

Comment: Go into the "Routines" tab, create a new routine, and change the Type from `PROCEDURE` to `FUNCTION`.

Comment: Thanks so much, bless you all!!